# Design of a 2d coordinate vector

Tags: haskell, types

I'm looking for a simple representation of a 2d coordinate vector. My first idea was a simple `(c, c)` tuple, but this doesn't suit my needs.

This is what I'd want:

- Instances of Functor and Applicative
- Ability to have distinct types that have the same semantics (e.g. `ScreenCoord` and `GameCoord`).
- Simple data constructors (e.g. `ScreenCoord c c`)
- Ability to write generic code over `Coord`.

I'm not sure on how to do this. Everything I've tried either required duplicating `instance` code to get the distinct types or it had long data constructors like `ScreenCoord (Coord c c)` which seemed unnecessary.

What would be the ideal representation here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in [Tensor](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Tensor) and [vector-space](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space)

[Vertex2](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/Tensor/1.0.0.1/doc/html/Data-Tensor.html#t%3aVertex2) and others from Vertex family represents points on the screen (not vectors). [vector-space-opengl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-opengl) provides appropriate instances of [vector-space](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space) .

Comment: Thanks for the links, but how could I create 'distinct synonyms' of 'Vertex2'? I am unsure if 'distinct synonyms' is the correct terminology.

Comment: @Pubby `newtype` is the mechanism for asking the type-checker to enforce a distinction between otherwise identical types.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. There is `newtype` declarations if you want to wrap existing data and create different instances for it. There is [NewtypeDeriving](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/NewtypeDeriving) language extension. There is [newtype](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/newtype) package to use `pack`/`unpack`. You can create own constructor-like functions.